# jQuery : Append text after an input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple input field :

```
<input type="text" id="someid" name="somename" class="someclass">
```

I'm trying to append some link right after this; so i'll get :

```
<input type="text" id="someid" name="somename" class="someclass"> - <a href="#">..</a>
```

i tried :

```
$("input#someid.someclass").append(' - <a href="#">Are you sure  ?</a>');
```

Without success, must be stupid but i can't find out what's wrong.

Comment: input element is a [void element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-elements) - meaning it cannot have content or children. `Append` adds a child, thus it doesn't work.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try .after() instead:

```
$("input#someid.someclass").after(' - <a href="#">Are you sure  ?</a>');
```

Answer (score 72):

Use after instead of append

```
$("input#someid.someclass").after(' - <a href="#">Are you sure  ?</a>');
```

Answer (score 8):

The `append` method will add the node you give it to the element you call it on.

In your case, you are putting the HTML *inside* the `INPUT` element.

You need to use the [`after`](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/after#content) method to insert the HTML after your `INPUT` element.

Answer (score -2):

```
$("input#someid.someclass").after($('<a>')
                           .attr('href','#').text('Are you sure  ?'));
```

Comment: `code`$("input#someid.someclass").after($('<a>').attr('href','#').text('Are you sure ?'));`code`

Comment: Could you add an explanation of your answer?